# refresh components in jframe in while loop

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I have a table in database contain image paths
and inside the `while` loop on the query result , i added the images to `JScrollPane`

```
while (rs.next()) {///loop on the image paths from database 
 //// i added here the images to JScrollPane
}
```

but the frame is freezing  until all the images set in `JScrollPane` then it shows to the user

***what i need :***
show the images in `JScrollPane` one by one and sorted without freezing the frame?!

---

note : i used `Thread` and fixed the problem but there are a problem in sorted

Comment: I think you should use SwingWorker to update your UI. Otherwise most of the times it will get freeze. You can use repaint or invalidate methods.

Comment: @ThusithaThilinaDayaratne SwingWorker! Not any thread. Swing is thread unsafe and it should be updated only on EDT.

Comment: @BranislavLazic Yes. Sorry and thanks for figuring out the mistake. I updated the comment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) to perform that task. Roughly speaking:

In `doInBackground` method you will fetch images from database and publish them by calling `publish` method within `doInBackground` method. Override `process` method and update your `JScrollPane` from there. Since it runs on [EDT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) where Swing components should be created and updated.

Answer (score 1):

You should process the time-consuming loop in another thread. If you don't do it, it will freeze the GUI until finished.

[This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SwingWorker#Usage_in_Java_6.0) link contains a way to do it in the most basic form.